# How to Simply Remove a Specific User_ID from Outputted List

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display a "Top 10 Leaderboard" list of users on my Wordpress website who have earned the most points using the popular MyCred plugin. The code I found is working perfectly, however against my wishes, myself as the admin always makes the top of this points list because I am on the website helping people all the time, therefore earning points. But, I don't want to be competitive with other users as admin.

**New to PHP, I'm having problems figuring out what I need to add to have it not include me — using my Wordpress user ID (#1) I assume — when it generates the "top 10" list.**

Here's [the complete code](https://gist.github.com/nadeem-khan/2ba59ef6337e8eb761bb) I'm working with that I found on GitHub, but I think the relevant small section of code I need to slightly modify is right here:

```
// Construct unorganized list for each row
             echo '<ul class="mycred-this-weeks-leaderboard">';
            foreach ($leaderboard as $position => $data) {
                echo '<li>';
                $user_info = get_userdata($data->user_id);
                $tempname = $user_info->user_login;
                $lowerstring = strtolower($tempname);
                $stringwithoutspace = strtr($lowerstring, ' ', '-');
                $username = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '-', $stringwithoutspace);

                ?>
                <?php if (!empty($username)) { ?>
                    <div class="leaderboard-info-block">                       
                        <span class="leaderboard-avatar"><?php echo $avatar = get_avatar($data->user_id, 49); ?></span> <span class="leaderboard-profile-link"><a href="<?php echo 'http://chillopedia.com/forums/users/' . $username; ?>"><?php echo $data->display_name; ?></a></span> <br>
                        <span class="leaderboard-user-points"><?php echo $mycred->format_creds($data->total); ?></span>
                    </div>    
                    <?php
                }
                echo '</li><br>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
```

Thank you for any help you can give me! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the code inside loop if the $data->user_id is 1 (your user ID)

```
if($data->user_id == 1){
    continue;
}
```

To implement that code to yours:

```
echo '<ul class="mycred-this-weeks-leaderboard">';
foreach ($leaderboard as $position => $data) {
    if($data->user_id == 1){
        continue;
    }
    echo '<li>';
    $user_info = get_userdata($data->user_id);
    $tempname = $user_info->user_login;
    $lowerstring = strtolower($tempname);
    $stringwithoutspace = strtr($lowerstring, ' ', '-');
    $username = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '-', $stringwithoutspace);

    ?>
    <?php if (!empty($username)) { ?>
        <div class="leaderboard-info-block">                       
            <span class="leaderboard-avatar"><?php echo $avatar = get_avatar($data->user_id, 49); ?></span> <span class="leaderboard-profile-link"><a href="<?php echo 'http://chillopedia.com/forums/users/' . $username; ?>"><?php echo $data->display_name; ?></a></span> <br>
            <span class="leaderboard-user-points"><?php echo $mycred->format_creds($data->total); ?></span>
        </div>    
        <?php
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you SO much Zunan!!!  It worked perfectly!  I appreciate your time, knowledge, and very clear and precise instructions for me. Makes me want to learn PHP even more now. :-)